# Read var from IO::SOCKET::SSL

Tags: perl

I try to apply a small patch to a nagios script to add a additional command line switch "--sslv3".

the original is line that need to be modified now is

```
$client = new IO::Socket::SSL->new(PeerAddr => $host,
    SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE);
```

and if $sslv3 is set the line should be like (note the additional SSL_version thing)

```
$client = new IO::Socket::SSL->new(PeerAddr => $host,
    SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE,  SSL_version => 'SSLv3');
```

I tried to solve it with an simple if like

```
$client = new IO::Socket::SSL->new(PeerAddr => $host,
    SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE,
    ($sslv3) ? SSL_version => 'SSLv3' : 
    SSL_version => $DEFAULT_SSL_ARGS{SSL_version});
```

but i can not get the default value from *perl/5.14.2/IO/Socket/SSL.pm* -  *IO::Socket::SSL* and think my way is not the best . This is the Part from the file where the default is defined:

```
# global defaults
my %DEFAULT_SSL_ARGS = (
SSL_check_crl => 0,
    SSL_version => 'SSLv23:!SSLv2',
    SSL_verify_callback => undef,
    SSL_verifycn_scheme => undef,  # don't verify cn
    SSL_verifycn_name => undef,    # use from PeerAddr/PeerHost
    SSL_npn_protocols => undef,    # meaning depends whether on server or client side
    SSL_cipher_list =>
        'EECDH+AESGCM+ECDSA EECDH+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA +AES256 EECDH EDH+AESGCM '.
        'EDH ALL +SHA +3DES +RC4 !LOW !EXP !eNULL !aNULL !DES !MD5 !PSK !SRP',
);
```

How can i access `SSL_version` and use it, or even do it in an cooler way?
I tried

```
print "ssl ver " . $DEFAULT_SSL_ARGS{SSL_version};
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you are asking. I think you're looking for

```
my %DEFAULT_SSL_ARGS = (
    ...
    $sslv3 ? (SSL_version => 'SSLv3') : (),
);
```

or the easier to read

```
my %DEFAULT_SSL_ARGS = (
    ...
);

$DEFAULT_SSL_ARGS{SSL_version} = 'SSLv3' if $sslv3;
```

Comment: `my $sslv3 = 0;  $client = new IO::Socket::SSL->new(PeerAddr => $host,SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE, ( $sslv3 ? SSL_version => 'SSLv3' : () ) );` is not working for me. throws compilation error `syntax error at [...], near "SSL_version =>"`. Maybe it is just a small syntax typo? i added some info to my first post. Script is from: [link](http://www.claudiokuenzler.com/nagios-plugins/check_ilo2_health-158.pl)

Comment: works, thanks for that! never seen the usage of `()` and creating an object with _named params_ before.

Comment: No such thing as named params; you're merely building a list. `()` is just a placeholder for an empty list, like in `@a = ();`.

Comment: thx for this hint. i begin to understand how perl syntax works :)